# Setting light to a derailleur

Tags: maintenance, derailleur

At 3:30ish in [this video](http://www.guardian.co.uk/environment/bike-blog/video/2013/mar/07/the-art-of-repair-bike-fix-video), they set light to a front derailleur. Why? Degreasing it? Waxy lube that needs melting in? I can't think of a good reason. Any ideas?

Comment: It looked cool and intentional, but it also looks like a really quick way to melt any bushings or plastic spacers in your FD.

Comment: I have heard of setting light to disc pads, but they are designed to get hot...

Comment: @mattnz one time I got oil on my disk pads. I threw both the pads and disks in a fire. The discs got cleaned up. The expensive pads **crumbled** immediately!

Comment: @Vorac: Yeh, that would happen... What you do is pour a teaspoon of meths on them and set that on fire.  The oil burns off without excessive heat.

Comment: @Vorac Were they 'Eco' type green pads? I've baked sintered pads in the oven and set them alight with alcohol, and never had crumbling. I'll be more careful now!

Comment: @Mere Development i think not, also they were red pads with sintered metal on the other side. The fire was a wooden campfire. It might have taken them several minutes, I do not remember.

Comment: Heat is commonly used as a last-resort to free up a stuck thread or metal fitting.  The heat makes the metal expand fractionally, allowing just enough space for penetrating oil to get in and do its thing.   Downside is heat will damage plastic and rubber, may damage paint and will definitely ignite volatiles.    I've used it as a second-last resort because after that is grinders and cutting the dead part off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I thought we needed an answer to this, so I just phoned the shop. He's a nice fellow (as you can tell from the vid) and said that his mechanic is convinced that this method works to free-up seized and corroded mechs. Apparently dousing it in something like GT85 and lighting it for a very short time boils in the lube, and works.

I assume that the combination of a penetrating lube, some heat, and vapour would achieve this as a last resort for badly seized metal components. I've done something similar on bearings when trying to get them out of BMX cups in the past.

Comment: Heat is a good way to loosen metal-metal fittings (for bearing cups but also stuck seatposts, pedal spindles, and quill stems) but I would never recommend it if there was a chance of melting or deforming any of the plastic components on modern derailleurs (or of lighting yourself or your home on fire...the same reason using gasoline as a degreaser is foolish.) A safer option would be to use a heat gun.

Comment: @WTHarper Yep I heartily agree! Care needed :)

Comment: Good sleuthing on that question.